# Difference between test expressions

Tags: javascript

I'm implementing obligatory slider in my project. And the following code worked fine:

```
else if( current - 1 === sliderLength ){
  current = 1;
  loc = 0
}
```

But this didn't work as expected:

```
else if( current === sliderLength - 1 ){
  current = 1;
  loc = 0
}
```

So, what is difference between `current === sliderLength - 1` and `current - 1 === sliderLength` ?

Comment: Seriously? The difference is that they're *completely different*. You're producing and comparing two different numbers in each case. This is something you should be looking at in a debugger or with log statements.

Comment: I'm with Chris, this should be very obvious - in fact writing this question took probably longer than you would have to think about it...

Comment: seriously, I'm not understanding the fact.

Comment: To be clear, I don't object to failing to see the problem; that's something which happens to everyone from time to time. But asking a question on SO should be a last resort after proper debugging, and running this through a debugger to see what numbers you're producing would show the difference.

Comment: I already stated that they both works differently so I mean I have checked console, but just not understanding the fact.

Comment: Assume `current` is 5 and `sliderLength` is 4 now how is both the cases compared

Comment: In case 1 you have `current - 1 === sliderLength` so it is `5-1 === 4`, but in case 2 you have `current === sliderLength - 1` so `5 === 4-1` - can you see the difference now

Comment: I guess you should have a look at the https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence to understand operator precedence.

Comment: what you need is `current === sliderLength + 1`

Comment: let's suggest that **current = 4** and **sliderLength = 5** then we'll have the following **(4) - 1 === 5** or **(4) === (5) - 1**
that's completely different!

Answer (score 2):

I will rename your variable to x and y for brevity, and just include the pertinent part:

`if (x - 1 === y)` vs `if (x === y - 1)`

If you have a hard time seeing the difference, just try them both out for some random values for x and y. Let's try `x = 3`, `y = 2`

So, the first one becomes:

`if (3 - 1 === 2)`, or `if ((3 - 1) === 2)`, or `if (2 === 2)` (i.e. `true`)

Second one becomes:

`if (3 === 2 - 1)`, or `if (3 === (2 - 1))`, or `if (3 === 1)` (i.e. `false`)

The important thing to note is that the comparison operation (`===`) happens after the subtraction operation. Actually that's not even that important in this case, but something to note.

Comment: Very educative explanation. Note that `===` doesn't test only for value equality, but also for *type* equality. Can this have an impact in the current case?

Answer (score 1):

let's take current = 6 and slider=5

Let's take an example

```
current - 1 === sliderLength  // 5 === 5  ; true statement

current === sliderLength - 1 // 6 ===4  ; that's a false statement
```

Answer (score 0):

wrap in math, (evaluate(nest))

```
else if( current === (sliderLength - 1) ){
  current = 1;
  loc = 0
}
```

or

```
else if( (current - 1) === sliderLength ){
  current = 1;
  loc = 0
}
```

Also consider data typing
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_datatypes.asp

compare
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp

math () vs eval()
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
else if( current === sliderLength + 1 ){
  current = 1;
  loc = 0
}
```